# Как сделать доступ к файлу через пароль

Tags: php

Надо сделать так: на сервере есть файл text.txt(к примеру) и ещё два файла `pass.php` и `ch.php` (от check). В `pass.php` есть форма ввода пароля, она обращается к `ch.php`. Затем `ch.php` должен проверять значение пароля через `if`. Если `$password = $rightPass`, то выводим файл text.txt (хочу вывести через `fopen` и `fread`, но знаний не хватает.). Если же пароль неверный, то через `else` выводим надпись неправильный пароль.

**pass.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Вход по понятиям.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 align="center">Братан, тут всё честно, войди по понятиям. </h1>
    <form align="center" name="authorization" action="ch.php" method="POST">
            <input style=" width: 800px; height: 100px; padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px; border:10px solid #999; font-size:16px; font-family: Tahoma;" type="password" name="pass" id="password" placeholder="Пароль"/>
            <button style=" width: 800px; height: 100px; padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px; border:10px solid #999; font-size:16px; font-family: Tahoma;" id="finishAuthorization">Вход.</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ch.php**

```
<?PHP
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$rightPass = 0145;
if ($password == $rightPass) {
 /*тут надо выводить text.txt через fopen и fread*/
} else {
  echo "Неверно";
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, который вы уже написали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чём проблема?

```
header('Content-type: text/plain;');
echo file_get_contents("text.txt");
```

Или

```
header('Content-type: text/plain;');
$filename="text.txt";
$fd=fopen($filename, "r");
echo fread($fd, filesize ($filename));
```

или так

```
header('Content-type: text/plain;');
include('text.txt');
```

А вообще [вот тут море информации](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-php-readfiles/)

Также в вашем коде нужно взять в кавычки пароль

```
$rightPass = '0145';
```

Comment: проблема в том, что когда я захожу на pass.php и ввожу правильный пароль, равный 0145 из переменной $rightPass, то при нажатии на кнопку "Войти" и переходе на ch.php конечный вывод из ch.php это "неверно", тоесть получается что из if выходит false. Тоесть $password не равен $rightPass

Comment: @Yexeed экранируйте верный пароль - $rightPass = '0145';

Comment: Ну неужели. Спасибо вам большое, рад что смог найти помощь на stackoverflow

Comment: @Yexeed потому что вы получаете через пост не число, а текст 0145. И потом пытаетесь сверить его с числом 0145. А это разные вещи. Потому и false

Comment: `0145` в восьмеричную систему случаем не преобразуется? Попробуйте ввести пароль 101 =)

Comment: @Yexeed Если считаете, что вопрос решён, то поставьте, пожалуйста, плюс и отметьте его галочкой. Буду признателен

Comment: @n.osennij как?

Comment: @Yexeed http://i.imgur.com/gr0s49K.png

Comment: @Yexeed Скриншот выше. Там две стрелочки. Первая плюсует. А вторая - ответить решённым.

Comment: @n.osennij плюсануть не могу, репутации не хватает, а вот галочку поставил

Comment: @Yexeed Спасибо. Успехов.